# Block popup windows settings give error to close popup window in JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have one web page, on which when user click on button (for calculation purpose) one popup window open (it's an aspx page as popup) .

When user done calculations on popup then automatically popup is close.

But when user block popup windows through browser setting then popup open but can't close.

I want to close this popup window even when user block popup windows.

Code for open popup window:

```
window.open('frmSelection.aspx?form=' + formname + '&controlname=' + controlname + '&caption=' + caption + '&control1=' + control1 + '&control2=' + control2 + '&control3=' + control3 + '&Filter=' + filter + '', null,
                                    'height=500,width=562,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=center');
```

Code for close popup window:

```
   protected void dgrdSelection_ItemCommand(object source, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "Select")
            {
                StringBuilder strScriptBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                strScriptBuilder.Append("<script language='javascript' type=text/javascript> ");

                strScriptBuilder.Append(" window.close(); ");
                strScriptBuilder.Append(" </script> ");
} 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use [jQuery load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) with [jQueryUI dialog()](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/), like [this](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/loading-existing-html-pages-into-a-jquery-dialog-window). So have no problem with popup blocker.